# modificar un csv y graficar con matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

Buenas soy estudiante y tengo este ejercicio. A partir de un CSV, me piden que actualice el precio de los prestadores de streaming, muestres promedio y los grafique. La actualización y el grafico no lo estoy logrando.
Para actualizar, se pide el prestador (servicio) y se actualiza el precio de cada plan, y el grafico se pide en columnas agrupadas.
Adjunto el archivo csv y py. Y un ejemplo del gráfico. Muchas gracias.

```
print('\n= actualizacion de precio =')

    actualizacion = input('ingrese el servicio: ').lower()
    if actualizacion in prestadores.keys():
        print(actualizacion)
        nuevo_precio = int(input(f'ingrese el precio nuevo para los planes de {actualizacion}')) 
        df_prestadores['plan'] = nuevo_precio.get('plan')
    
    else:
        print('\ningreso un servicio inexistente')
        print('producots con existencia')
        for producto in stock:
        #    print(f'  > {producto}')
```

[para descargar el py y el csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmBvu90bFqXngewr0SSm1NA9I6n9AQ?e=3uaEqJ)

como deberia quedar el grafico[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una lectura del archivo con el modulo pandas (read_csv https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) una vez cargados los datos puedes tratarlos como arrays de numpy para graficarlos (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-plot-an-array-in-python-using-matplotlib), ya sea en pandas o en numpy, existen métodos para hacer las estadisticas para cada conjunto de datos que se desee.

Comment: Logro leer el csv y realizar algo muy básico de estadística. Sin embargo, no estoy entendiendo como, por ej, buscar el prestador (netflix) y actualizar el precio de los 3 planes que tiene (dentro de panda)